# Excel vlookup/Macro to calculate trade data

Tags: excel, vba, formula, vlookup

I'll try and be as specific as I can while being mindful that the data is sensitive. I currently have a workbook which contains individual worksheets detailing each days trading activity, broken down by client name, stock traded etc. On the master worksheet within this workbook, I would like to have end of week/month trading figures summarised from each individual sheet/day.

So, for example: the master worksheet will show that in October, client x traded 500m volume of stock, by adding the figures on the individual sheets.

In order to do this, is there a vlookup I can implement in my master worksheet which will lookup a particular client name in each individual worksheet, sum the revenue for that client and add it on the master worksheet? Or would I need to go down the vba route? I understand its a rather vague request so any guidance would be much appreciated.

I've included a screenshot of the column labels to give some idea of the data:

[Individual day worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwDmj.png)

Comment: This is a bit too broad and might be put on hold until you can be a little more specific, be mindful to show a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
You can achieve this with SUMIFS and fields containing your client name, date, class of product, etc, but Excel might not be the proper tool for this sort of job, for a vast number of reasons, including performance and the limitation of total rows.

Comment: Thanks, I've added a screenshot of the column labels for the individual worksheet in order to hopefully give everyone a bit of an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Given your sensitive information, I'll give you a generic answer that you can further adapt to your case.

You can use the SUMIFS function in excel as a VLOOKUP with multiple criteria, that may be suitable for this sort of problem. Let's say that your "Master" worksheet has only the fields Client Name and Date (month) on columns A and B, and you wish to fill the column C (Trade Volume) with the sum of monthly trades on your 'Trades' sheet, as in:

```
A           | B            | C
Client Name | Date (month) | Trade Volume
Bob         | 01-10-2018   | 500,000.00
Jack        | 01-11-2018   | 245,000.00
```

And one more condition, let's say your 'Trades' Sheet has the Client name on the first column (A), the Date of the given trade on the second column (B) and the volume of the trade on the third column (C)

You could use the following function on the cell C2 to achieve this sort of result:

```
=SUMIFS('Trades'!C:C, 'Trades'!A:A=A2, 'Trades'!B:B>= B2, 'Trades'!B:B<=EOMONTH(B2,0))
```

You may add more conditions to this formula, if necessary.

Comment: thanks @fabio.avigo. Would I need to constantly update the sumifs formula as I continue to add more worksheets to the excel file? Also, am I correct in understanding that your example should be used on an empty master worksheet? As of yet I have not inputted any data on the master

Comment: @NHure92 I would strongly suggest keeping your trades on a single worksheet: Adding a worksheet for each client might create a huge performance (and memory) overhead, as well as overcomplicating your formulas. One way to organize this is to replicate this workbook periodically, but then again, if you have a huge amount of trades, Excel may not be the proper tool for this job.

Comment: If by master worksheet you mean a worksheet to consolidate data, then yes, my example is to be used on an empty worksheet, but it can be adapted. I have written it this way to make it simpler to interpret.

Comment: @NHure92 a small reminder: I see you have asked several questions on Stack Overflow, but not accepted any answers. Please be sure to accept one answer to each of your question, should they solve your issue, so as to close the topic and show the community your token of appreciation. Thanks.